# How to test a custom element which includes other modules?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, web-component, custom-element, web-component-tester

Is there a way to test a custom element (using WCT) which includes an external module (let's say a `npm` one) or another custom element?

For instance I'm trying to test a custom element that looks like:

```
// ~/root/src/index.js
import CustomElementChildren from '~/path-to-children';
import NpmModule from 'npm-module';

export default class CustomElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

      if(!customElements.get('custom-element-children')){
      customElements.define('custom-element-children', CustomElementChildren);
    }
  }

  // implement some methods that are related with "NpmModule"

  connectedCallback() {
    this.initShadowDom();
  }

  initShadowDom() {
    let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    shadowRoot.innerHTML = this.template;
  }

  get template() {
    return `
      <div><custom-element-children></custom-element-children></div>
    `
  }
}
```

```
// ~/root/test/index-test.html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="eng">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@webcomponents/shadydom"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@webcomponents/custom-elements"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/web-component-tester/browser.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="../src/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<custom-element></custom-element>
<script>
  suite('<custom-element>', function() {
    let component = document.querySelector('custom-element');

    test('renders div', () => {
      assert.isOk(component.shadowRoot.querySelector('div'));
    });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The issues occured are related to syntax (import/export/et. c.) and I can't find a working way to setup webpack/babel for WCT.

Similar issue [here](https://github.com/Polymer/tools/issues/567), but can't say it's identical with my question, since I'd like to be able to use absolute imports as well.

Thank y'all in advance.

Comment: Ended setting up a webpack from the ground up.

Comment: If what you have works for you can you please "close" this question? if there are still some unanswered questions then I would take a look at https://open-wc.org/testing/